# Registering a Firebreath .dll from local hard drive in Firefox

Tags: javascript, activex, npapi, firebreath

How can I register a Firebreath .dll file thats deployed locally on a users hard drive.

In IE, I can use ShellExecute in JavaScript to run a shell command to register the .dll
How can I do the same for an NPAPI browser ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't register a .dll from inside the browser; if IE is letting you call ShellExecute from javascript that frightens me greatly. You certainly can't do that from firefox.

The recommended way to install a FireBreath plugin is using an MSI file (which is built-in if you have WiX 3.5 or later installed when you run the prep script), though alternate methods include wrapping that MSI in an EXE installer, using an XPI/CRX/CAB file (though that doesn't work on Safari and only the CAB file of those three can install for all browsers).

You can't directly register it from the browser.